# Why is my python 3 EAN query not working?

Tags: python-3.x

today I tried to program a EAN query with an EAN database.
I tried to put the request into a json but every time I get an error.

If the query was succesful, you get the data in an MIME-Typ text/plain text format.

What can I do?

Here is my code:

```
import json
import requests

userid = "&queryid=400000000"

base_url = "http://opengtindb.org/?ean="
query = "&cmd=query"

while True:
    print("Welcome to the EAN Database!")
    print()
    print("1: Search for API")
    print("2: Exit")
    choice = input("> ")

    if choice == "2":
        break

    if choice == "1":
        print("Enter the EAN Number")
        print()
        ean = input("> ")
        ean_call = base_url + ean + query + userid
        request = requests.get(ean_call)
        print(request.raw)
        print(request)
        data = request.json()
        print(data)
        data = data['body']
        print(ean)
        print(data)
        print(ean_call)
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/leon/PycharmProjects/ean_api.py", line 28, in <module>
    data = request.json()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: I added the link to the picture with the error.

Comment: Please do not add images of code. To learn more on how to ask in Stack Overflow, please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Now I put the error in the code block.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?